# Why cannot capture network logs when using chrome remotewebdriver in selenium grid?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, google-chrome-headless, network-traffic

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I want to capture network traffic when using web automation tests with Selenium Grid (Actually, I am using VMs to deploy the selenium grid architecture (Hub and Nodes)). Below is the code I am using in order to get the network logs:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.INFO);
chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
chromeOptions.setCapability("platform", platform);
chromeOptions.addArguments(
                    "--headless",
                    "--verbose",
                    "--disable-web-security",
                    "--allow-insecure-localhost",
                    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
                    "--allow-running-insecure-content",
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--disable-popup-blocking",
                    "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
                    "--silent"
            );
this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.10.10:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
this.driver.get(website);

List<LogEntry> entries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE).getAll();
System.out.println(entries.size() + " " + LogType.PERFORMANCE + " log entries found");
for (LogEntry entry : entries) {
    System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
}
```

**But I get this error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found
  (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.108)
System info: host: 'themadmalik', ip: '***.***.***.***', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 78.0.3904.108, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a81..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.tNFy6o}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:45465}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 06521c2b5573343d789ba1302c4...}
```

Someone know how can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/8457 and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.59/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.java and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/01bf9a0372b98a50026b6a4411504ce8341f3c51#diff-97fe466d7329ff8e94aac62b8e55c55a03ddf7fd0a8e33414b64972f93d7cbd1